# Can you create a volumegroup in LVM that all the Logical volumes created under it will be thin provisioned?

Tags: linux, rhel, lvm

I would like to know if it is possible to create a volumegroup in LVM that all the Logical volumes created under it will be thin provisioned?

This will be used on RHEL 6 which does include thin provisioning in LVM.

I am open to alternatives as well.

Comment: Thin provisioning for LVM is INCREDIBLY new. As in the only release of RHEL that supports is the very latest release (kind of surprised they would do that smack dab in the middle of a major version, but oh well I guess). As such, they've just now gotten to where you can do it at all. That said, they probably won't add this functionality for a while. I mean, they've supported snapshots forever, but there's no option for those to be the default in a volume group either. Not saying they won't add that, just saying it isn't like that and it's probably going to stay like that for a while.

Comment: Alright thanks for the response. Hopefully they will add it soon.

Comment: If you fill up the VG with one big thin-pool, then you'll have no option but to create thin LVs in it since there will be no space left for any other type of LV. Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Well I have a piece of software that creates the lv inside the volumegroup. I create the volumegroup and I enter its name in the software. The program doesn't have an option to make a thin provisioned lv so I wanted to know if it was possible to create a Vg that could only make thin provisioned lv's. If that makes sense

Comment: @JoelDavis RedHat has a history of releasing significant changes to LVM in the middle of their RHEL release cycles. They're also the primary developers of LVM, so I'm guessing they just trust their own code.

Comment: Why? Is your storage not able to provide thin provisioned targets? What is your use case here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can create a volumegroup for thin provisioning. The following are the detail steps, copied from [here](https://lxadm.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/lvm-thin-provisioning/):

> ```
> # pvcreate /dev/sdd
> Writing physical volume data to disk "/dev/sdd"
> Physical volume "/dev/sdd" successfully created
> ```
>
> I can see now that I have a new physical volume.
>
> ```
> # pvdisplay
> "/dev/sdd" is a new physical volume of "1.36 TiB"         --- NEW Physical volume ---         PV Name /dev/sdd        VG Name         PV Size 1.36 TiB
>   Allocatable NO      PE Size 0       Total PE 0      Free PE 0       Allocated PE 0
>   PV UUID Ndb90e-xkJX-Lagt-VePO-ZNLQ-udVn-SN65et
> ```
>
> Next we need to create a volume group.
>
> ```
>   # vgcreate vg_1 /dev/sdd        Volume group "vg_1" successfully created
> ```
>
> Now that we have both the physical volume and volume group, lets add
>   some logical volumes. To begin, we want to add a logical volume pool
>   to hold our thinly provisioned volumes within it.
>
> ```
>   # lvcreate --size 10G --type thin-pool --thinpool thin_pool vg_1
>   Rounding up size to full physical extent 4.00 MiB       Logical volume
> ```
>
> "thin_pool" created
>
> I created a 10GB pool for this test.
>
> ```
>   # lvs       LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy% Convert
>   thin_pool vg_1 twi-a-tz 10.00g 0.00
> ```
>
> Now we can add the thin volume itself, a 4GB logical volume within
>   thin_pool.
>
> ```
>   # lvcreate -V4G -T vg_1/thin_pool --name lv1        Logical volume "lvl"
> ```
>
> created
>
> Now that we have everything created, lets look at what we have.
>
> ```
>   # lvs       LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy% Convert
>   lv1 vg_1 Vwi-a-tz 4.00g thin_pool 0.00      thin_pool vg_1 twi-a-tz
> ```
>
> 10.00g 0.00
>
> You can see when calling lvs that 0% of the lv is taken so far.
>
> Next let’s format the new logical volume, and mount it.
>
> ```
>   # mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg_1/lv1       # mount /dev/vg_1/lv1 /mnt
> ```
>
> With df we can see that 4GB is available.
>
> ```
>   # df -h         ...         /dev/mapper/vg_1-lv1 4.0G 136M 3.7G 4% /mnt
> ```
>
> Our used space comes from the filesystem and we can see with lvs that
>   the orgin data is filling up.
>
> ```
>   # lvs       LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy% Convert
>   lv1 vg_1 Vwi-aotz 4.00g thin_pool 4.73      thin_pool vg_1 twi-a-tz
> ```
>
> 10.00g 1.89
>
> Copying a iso image into our thin lv we can see it expand further.
>
> ```
>   # cp /home/sean/Downloads/ubuntu-12.10-beta2-server-amd64.iso /mnt
>   # lvs       LV VG Attr LSize Pool Origin Data% Move Log Copy% Convert
>   lv1 vg_1 Vwi-aotz 4.00g thin_pool 7.73      thin_pool vg_1 twi-a-tz
> ```
>
> 10.00g 6.37       # df -h         ....        /dev/mapper/vg_1-lv1 4.0G 827M 3.0G 22% /mnt
>
> Lastly, looking at our thin pool, you can also see the space taken
>   within the pool by the thin lv.
>
> ```
> # lvdisplay
> --- Logical volume ---
> LV Name thin_pool
> VG Name vg_1
> LV UUID kD3VC1-FBNj-wHER-iFhE-NjES-GDoS-sFCnwF
> LV Write Access read/write
> LV Creation host, time fedora, 2012-10-11 21:43:51 -0700
> LV Pool transaction ID 1
> LV Pool metadata thin_pool_tmeta
> LV Pool data thin_pool_tdata
> LV Pool chunk size 64.00 KiB
> LV Zero new blocks yes
> LV Status available
> # open 0
> LV Size 10.00 GiB
> Allocated pool data 8.64%
> Allocated metadata 4.30%
> Current LE 2560
> Segments 1
> Allocation inherit
> Read ahead sectors auto
> - currently set to 256
> Block device 253:4
>
>
> --- Logical volume ---
> LV Path /dev/vg_1/lv1
> LV Name lv1
> VG Name vg_1
> LV UUID b7FLSq-dMTi-mEbl-vZxq-Ocol-9Y2o-AEBhgL
> LV Write Access read/write
> LV Creation host, time fedora, 2012-10-11 21:44:11 -0700
> LV Pool name thin_pool
> LV Status available
> # open 1
> LV Size 4.00 GiB
> Mapped size 21.60%
> Current LE 1024
> Segments 1
> Allocation inherit
> Read ahead sectors auto
> - currently set to 256
> Block device 253:5
> ```

Comment: That's a nice answer to the question of how to create a volume group, and a thin provisioned lv within it, but that's not what the question asked.

Comment: You are right... psusi. I shouldn't try to rush things...

Comment: This answer is a direct copy of http://lxadm.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/lvm-thin-provisioning/

Answer (score 1):

The answer right now I believe is 'kind of not really'. I've been using this feature for a few days now on Ubuntu 14.04, and it seems that the thinpool feature has been added as a type of logical volume, rather than at the volume group level, which seems like a weird abstraction break IMO (there are probably reasons, won't speculate here). Anyway, you can make a thinpool that takes up almost the whole volume group (lvcreate complains if you make it the same exact size), and then alias a command or write a script that calls lvcreate with the thinpool name prepopulated, and you'll basically have what you want.